# mudança de tabela ao seu chamada em . lua?

Tags: lua, tabela-html, lua-table

tenho essa tabela abaixo

```
tabela = {
    ["Maquina"] = {
        {name = "susu", level = 600},
        {name = "camel", level = 600},
        {name = "juju", level = 600},
    },
    ["bruno"] = {
        {name = "fada", level = 600},
        {name = "pinoquio", level = 600},
        {name = "jupter", level = 600},
    }
}
```

como posso fazer para quanto eu chamar ela os valores mudem sempre ex abaixo

```
tabela = {
    ["Maquina"] = {
        {name = "camel", level = 600},
        {name = "juju", level = 600},
        {name = "susu", level = 600},
    },
    ["bruno"] = {
        {name = "pinoquio", level = 600},
        {name = "fada", level = 600},
        {name = "jupter", level = 600},
    }
}
```

Comment: Sua pergunta não faz sentido, em Lua uma tabela não é "chamada".

Comment: Amigo, pelo que entendi você deseja é apenas mudar a ordenação? correto?

Comment: sim , exatamente